# Ползунок изменяющий два значения

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, jquery-ui

Я новичок и столкнулся с проблемой.
Нужно сделать ползунок, который меняет 2 значения, первое значение - квадратура потолка, второе значение - цена за работу.
Перерыл кучу документаций, но так и не понял как сделать именно с двумя значениями...

[image: ПРИМЕР]

Comment: Так же будет очень хорошо, если подскажите, можно ли отправлять эти данные после нажатия на кнопку, на почту

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос будет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кучу не кучу, но это азы азов ;)
[Ссылка](https://learn.javascript.ru/attributes-and-custom-properties) с полезной информацией

```js
let inputValue = document.querySelector('input'); // получаем элемент ввода
let meters = document.querySelector('.meters'); // получаем элемент вывода №1
let sum = document.querySelector('.sum'); // получаем элемент вывода №2

inputValue.addEventListener('input', () => { // добавляем слушатель событий, первым аргументом - название слушателя, вторым колбэк (то что будет выполняться, в данном случае - стрелочная функция
  meters.value = inputValue.value // присваиваем элементу вывода №1 значение элемента ввода
  sum.value = meters.value * 3 // присваиваем элементу вывода №2 значение элемента вывода №1 (и тут уже ваша формула, + / - * %)
});
```

```css
input {display: block;margin-bottom: 10px;}input[readonly] {border: none;outline: none;}
```

```html
<input type="range" value="0" max="100">
<input readonly class="meters">
<input readonly class="sum">
```